# which is a better way to handle long running synchronous/blocking tasks in node

Tags: node.js, child-process, event-loop

So lets say we want to find the sum of all the numbers in a very very long array. There two ways I can do it without blocking the event loop.

1. using node using child process
2. creating a asynchronous function to add and use that to find the sum of all the numbers.

   ```
   import awaitEach from 'await-each';


   function makeItAsync(myFunc){
    return function(...args){

      return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        setImmediate(function(){
          var result = myFunc(...args);
          resolve(result);
        });
     });

    }
   }

   function add(a,b){ return a + b}

   var asyncAdd = makeItAsync(add);

   var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.........];
   var sum = 0;

   await awaitEach(list, async function(n){
       sum = await asyncAdd(n,sum);
   })

   console.log(sum);
   ```

using asyncAdd and looping asynchronously in the array can be one of the solutions to do long running task without blocking.

Would like to know which is better in terms of performance(cpu, memory).

- Is one of these more better approach under high number of requests.
- Which one is faster.
- Which one takes more memory.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts a tick later, it will again call asyncAdd and again the process will continue

Answer (score 4):

`setImmediate()` and `setTimeout()` may appear to make something asynchronous because they don't immediately block, but they don't really solve the problem of long-running blocking tasks.  They schedule the tasks to run later, but when it runs, it will still be a long-running task that blocks the event loop until its done.  So, your `makeItAsync()` function is really no more useful than just running the original function with a `setTimeout()`.

If you have a long running task and you don't want to block the event loop for very long, these are your main options:

1. Break the long running tasks into very small pieces of work that can each be done in a few milliseconds.  After you finish one piece of work, schedule the next piece of work with a short `setTimeout()` and this will allow the event loop to process other events in between your pieces of work.  This typically requires a major rewrite of the long running task (almost into a state machine) and can sometimes be downright hard to architect and maintain for some types of processing.
2. Fire up a child process and farm out the long running task to the child process. Then, your main event loop is entirely free of the long running tasks.  The child process can just communicate back a result when its done.  If you have to run this task a lot, you can create a work queue and a set of child processes that munch on the tasks in the queue, sending a message back to the parent whenever they are done.  This is generally fairly easy to do.  Once drawback is that the child process doesn't have direct access to the data in the main process so if the long running tasks needs access to lots of data from the main process, then you have to architect a way to share the data (perhaps putting the data into another process such as redis where multiple processes can access it).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think I did not make it very clear In my question, but I am actually breaking down my long running task of adding a list of N numbers into N async tasks. asyncAdd is the function which will be called serially in a loop. Have added some more code the question, to explain it better